# Index out of bounds with itertuples

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have a dataframe like this :

```
user_id anime_id    user_rating
0   1   20  7.808497
1   3   20  8.000000
2   5   20  6.000000
3   6   20  7.808497
4   10  20  7.808497
```

it looks like basic dataframe for playing with recommender system.

i had ~ 7millions rows, I reduced a bit the dataframe like that :

```
df = df[df["user_id"] < 2000]
```

let's print n_users, n_items, i had 1999 users of course, and ~6000items

I have 2 problems. 
if i want to built my training dataset like that :

```
ratings = np.zeros((n_users, n_items))
for row in df.itertuples():
    ratings[row[1]-1, row[2]-1] = row[3]
```

i have an  `IndexError:

```
index 950 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 949`
```

I tried new things with row[0] following comment it doesn't work :

```
X = urm[["user_id", "anime_id"]].as_matrix()
y = urm["user_rating"].values
n_u = len(urm["user_id"].unique())
n_m = len(urm["anime_id"].unique())

R = np.zeros((n_u, n_m))
for idx, row in enumerate(X):
    R[row[0]-1, row[1]-1] = y[idx]
```

still the same IndexError.

if i pass a line with if row in R.index : code return only np.zeros matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row[1]` represents `user_id`, not your dataframe index. As soon as you reach a row with `user_id` greater than the first dimension of `ratings`, you will see an `IndexError`. Instead, use `row[0]` or `row.Index` to extract the row index, which you can then use to index the `ratings` array.

In addition, note that `df[df["user_id"] < 2000]` in itself does not guarantee you have 1999 users. For example, some `user_id` integer identifiers may be missing.

Comment: I understand, but can you give me an exemple ? i tried to match ratings [row[0]-1, row[1]-1] = row[2] but it still the same problem with index, moreover i think that will result of an output different that one i want.